# PHP Referal Error

Tags: php

Im trying to make a php refferall system, Some of my current code is below. But when i go to the url it says page not found? Is there a way to avoid that.

```
<?php
if (substr($_GET['page'], 0, 9) === 'referall/') 
{ 
    //Heres where it says page not found
    $ref = substr( $url, strrpos( $_GET['page'], '/' )+1 );     
    //So i go to say http://example.com/referall/Me and it says not found
    //The get ['page'] is the / of the website like http://example.com/index
}
switch ($_GET['page'])
{
    case "login": { //Index page }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not your php fault for that. Are you using codeigniter or some framework?

Comment: Im using xampp to host my website? and my php is just written by myself in notepad? I dont understand fully what you mean.

Comment: In that case, GET arguments are not passed like this: http://example.com/referall/Me but rather like this: **http://example.com?page=referall&person=Me** and it shoud work

Comment: Is there a way to do / ? Even if it means changing GET arguments to something other? In the htaccses...

Comment: Yes! but rather then doing it on your own, personally I can recommend using Codeigniter, it has really good documentation to start in 5min

Comment: Minor observation: The person who defined the [`Referer` header in HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) couldn't spell it, either, and it's caused us problems for nearly two decades. If you're going to develop a referral system, it's worth at least being consistent, and it'd be even better to spell the word correctly, too... Future users of your system who *can* spell the word will thank you, especially if they're typing out your referral links.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that, then you cannot use your URL in a way you are using:

> example.com/referall/Me

bacause GET arguments are not passed to your code
but rather then use this URL:

> example.com?page=referall&person=Me

and it shoud work.

If still you want to do that in a way you imagined, consider to use some framework that can make things easier for you, there are many of them, personally I recommend Codeigniter